# How to track where the right callout accessory view is when it was tapped on

Tags: iphone, objective-c

As you can see below I have an annotation view that has a right button.  When the user taps the right button I am presenting a popover - the problem is I don't know where the user tapped so I don't have the X and Y to display the popover accordingly.

How do I find out where the user tapped i.e. the X and Y?

```
HotelAnnotationView *customPinView = [[HotelAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:theHotel reuseIdentifier:hotelPin];

//The right button which allows user to see hotel information
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailsForHotel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

rightButton.tag = theHotel.id;
customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply implement

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Which will get called on your delegate everytime a user taps the calloutAccessoryControl. You can then access you annotation properties through

```
view.annotation
```

The reason I like this approach better than using the (id)sender is that you actually get access to not only your annotation lat & long coordinates, but any data that is actually associated with it so you can use that in your pop over view.

Answer (score 1):

Your action method `showDetailsForHotel:` includes the `sender` argument, which is the button that has been tapped. You can ask it for its coordinates like any view.