# iPhone App, Mapkit different rightbutton view per annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, mapkit

New to Objective C and IOS Development so hope someone can help. Ive got an app working with Mapkit. Each annotation has a callout and a right button that loads a new view. My issue is that the view that loads is the same for all annotations and I need it to be unique.

Heres the .m

```
#import "CoffeeViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "annotation.h"
#import "Options.h"

@implementation CoffeeViewController
@synthesize mapView,options;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void) gotoLocation {
    //start by default in london
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = 51.519853;
    newRegion.center.longitude = -0.122223;
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.112872;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.109863;

    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLLocation *userLoc = mapView.userLocation.location;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLoc.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",userCoordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",userCoordinate.longitude);
    mapView.delegate=self;

    NSMutableArray* annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
    theCoordinate1.latitude = 51.465264;
    theCoordinate1.longitude = -0.126858;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate2;
    theCoordinate2.latitude = 51.549324;
    theCoordinate2.longitude = -0.132866;

    annotation* myAnnotation1=[[annotation alloc] init];

    myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
    myAnnotation1.title=@"Monmouth Coffee Company";
    myAnnotation1.subtitle=@"Excellent Coffee";

    annotation* myAnnotation2=[[annotation alloc] init];

    myAnnotation2.coordinate=theCoordinate2;
    myAnnotation2.title=@"L J Coffee House";
    myAnnotation2.subtitle=@"Good Times";

    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation2];

    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation1];
    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation2];

    NSLog(@"%d",[annotations count]);

    MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {
        NSLog(@"fly to on");
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x,annotationPoint.y, 0,0);

                                            if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
                                                flyTo = pointRect;
                                            } else {
                                                flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
                                            }

                                            }

                                            mapView.visibleMapRect = flyTo;


                                            }



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"Welcome to the map view annotation");
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
    pinView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"coffeeicon.png"];
    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SwitchView:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coffeeicon.png"]];
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
    [profileIconView release];
    return pinView;

}

- (IBAction)SwitchView:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Annotation Click");

    Options *OptionsView = [[Options alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:OptionsView animated:YES];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please see answer to [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269558/how-to-track-where-the-right-callout-accessory-view-is-when-it-was-tapped-on

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are reused in flyweight pattern like UITableView does with it's cells.

You use the method in your delegate.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:viewForAnnotation:

And deque like the docs state.

See this for an example.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial